# Flipping a UIViewController managed by a UINavigationController hides navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm 2 levels down on a UINavigationContoller having already pushed a few views. Now I'm looking at an image inside one of the pushed view controllers and when I tap an info button in the navigation bar, I want the sub view to flip leaving the nav bar in place. How do I get just the subview (the view that was pushed) to flip? Right now the nav bar also flips and prevents me from navigating back up my stack.

```
-(void)showImageInfo
{   
    self.imgInfoViewController = [[ImageInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageInfoViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.imgInfoViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.imgInfoViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code from UICatalog Example.... I think it will do what you are looking for. Basically you have to do some more coding to get the flip behavior.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/TransitionViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-TransitionViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_34

```
  - (IBAction)flipAction:(id)sender
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:([self.mainView superview] ? UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft :UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)                                      forView:self.containerView  cache:YES];
        if ([flipToView superview])
        {
            [self.flipToView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.containerView addSubview:mainView];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.mainView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.containerView addSubview:flipToView];
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```